# Posting Screenshot of GameOver to FaceBook via Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cocos2d-iphone

I have searched a lot of forums and thread about posting screenshot on facebook. I have found the functon which is to be added in `CCDirector` which creates Screenshot. I have also seen the method which post the screenshot on facebook in an album or wall. But that is not working for me.

```
UIImage *tempImage = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] screenshotUIImage];

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   tempImage,@"message",
                                   nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
```

screenshotUIImage is the function that makes screenshot and it is working alright.
`requestWithGraphPath` does not do any thing for me. I have used different keywords in params like "tempImage, @"source"," and "tempImage, @"image"," but nothing happens.

However posting text on wall, like high score with predefined image link is working alright.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               imageSrc, @"picture",
                               serverLink, @"link",
                               postName, @"name",
                               customMessage, @"caption",
                               nil];

// Post on Facebook.
[_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Can any one guide me through how to do the picture posting?

Answer (score 1):

In your params, you can try specifying a UIImage for the the key "picture":

```
UIImage *tempImage = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] screenshotUIImage];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];    
[params setObject:myCaption forKey:@"caption"];
[params setObject:myMessage forKey:@"message"];
...
// UIImage object goes here
[params setObject:tempImage forKey:@"picture"];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still do not work for me. On sharing button it switches to facebook permission page. After pressing okey button on facebook page it switches back to game but nothing happens. If I post simple text using this line '[_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];' it ask permission and when it switches back to game there is a dialogue for facebook login on game screen. After login it shows the text to share with a share button and it work perfect. No dialogue while doing picture sharing using requestWithGraphPath. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work? Perhaps you can try posting an image via Sharekit instead. In fact, check out: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/blob/master/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Facebook/SHKFacebook.m#L247 to see how they implement UIImage posting via the FB Graph API. Apparently, it was done similarly.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it to do that way. hope this time it works.